# How do I take multiple floats from Scanner and store them separately in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, floating-point, average

I'm writing a program which should take five doubles from user input and return the average of them.

I want the program to take an input like

```
5.0 8.0 5.0 7.0 5.0
```

and return

```
6.0
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class findAverage {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Initialise the array
    float[] numberArray;
    float total = 0;

    // Allocate memory for 5 floats
    numberArray = new float[5];

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        numberArray[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        total += numberArray[i];
    }

    // Find the average
    float average = total / 5;
    System.out.println(average);
    }
}
```

Right now, that code takes user input 5 separate times and computes the average. How do I make it so the user can input 5 floats on the same line and have the program find the average?

Comment: You can input them on the same line. Simply hit enter afterwards, and Java will process them all at once.

Comment: Also, you are calling `nextInt`, while you are storing the result in a array of type `float`. Anyways, it looks as if you don't need the array at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to take an arbitrary number (N) of parameters and calculate the average without O(N) memory complexity, you can use the below.

Just make sure that you pass a non-number at the end of your list of parameters, like a 'a' or anything else that the Scanner doesn't ignore to make it stop.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    double avg = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1; ;i++)
    {
        if (!keyboard.hasNextDouble()) break;
        double next = keyboard.nextDouble();
        avg = (avg * (i - 1) + next) / i;
    }
    System.out.println(avg);
}
```

Comment: How to tell when there is end of the line, as this code will not calculate anything when you hit enter.

Comment: I told you. Put a non number at the end. Like  1 2 3 4 a

Comment: Ok, but in that case... don't you program the logic using exceptions? I understand that it works somehow, but exceptions are really not for controlling the normal logic flow.

Comment: the Scanner will throw if you pass it a non double. It is one possible way to get out of the loop there with a one-liner. One possible way, you can find out one that you like more. As for Exceptions are not really there for controlling the normal flow, it may be true in most cases. Some programming languages take another approach (Python with its iterators for example). I gave you something that works and is legal code. The idea of not storing the numbers in an array is beneficial

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible to do it using Scanner, but...

**YOU CAN DO IT LIKE THIS:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Avg {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        float total = 0;
        String line = keyboard.readLine();
        String[] data = line.split("\\s");
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {   
            total += Float.parseFloat(data[i]);
        }

        // Find the average
        float average = total / data.length;
        System.out.println(average);
    }
}
```

it will read all the floats entered in one line and print the average when you hit "enter".